# Loop through date and assign value as week number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with a date column. I would like to create a new column and assign value for every 7 days as week 1, week 2... I have learned that `df.iloc[::7, :]` will do the loop but how to assign values to the new column. Thank you.

```
Date        Week
1/1/2020    1
2/1/2020    1
3/1/2020    1
...
8/1/2020    2
9/1/2020    2
```

Comment: Are you looking for calendar week or just every 7 days of DF?

Comment: @PacketLoss: Currently just every 7 days

Comment: There are duplicate dates?

Comment: @MrNobody33: No there are not

Comment: And, does all the dataframe have the same structure? I mean, oredered ascendent by day dates ? @Jason

Comment: Yes, I can sort it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general solution subtract minimal date, convert timedeltas to days and use integer division by `7` with adding `1`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

df['Week'] = df['Date'].sub(df['Date'].min()).dt.days // 7 + 1
print (df)
         Date  Week
0 2020-01-01     1
1 2020-01-02     1
2 2020-01-03     1
3 2020-01-08     2
4 2020-01-09     2
```

---

If there are consecutive datetimes with no duplicates divide helper array by length of rows with `7` and add `1` (but it failed if miss only 1 date):

```
df['Week'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is built-in functionality to convert from date to week of year:  `pd.DatetimeIndex.weekofyear`.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd

n = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [*range(n)]},
             index = pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-01', periods = n, freq='4D')
            )
df['week-number'] = df.index.weekofyear
print(df)

            data  week-number
2020-01-01     0            1
2020-01-05     1            1
2020-01-09     2            2
2020-01-13     3            3
2020-01-17     4            3
```

`weekofyear` is deprecated in pandas version 1.1.0.  More info here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekofyear.html

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the initial date (row 1) from the current date.  Convert to days (integer).  divide `//` by 7 and add 1; that's your week number.

Can you take the coding from there?

```
week_num = int(current_date - Date[0]) // 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Date column is a `datetime.date` type, then `isocalendar()` will return a 3-tuple containing ISO year, week number, and weekday:

```
In [10]: d = datetime.date(2020,1,1)

In [11]: d.isocalendar()
Out[11]: (2020, 1, 3)

In [12]: d = datetime.date(2020,1,8)

In [13]: d.isocalendar()
Out[13]: (2020, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks but there is error: ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'```

Answer (score 0):

One liner, just because:

```
df = df[['Date']]
df['Week_no'] = [pd.Period(df['Date'].iloc[k]).week for k in df.index]
```